# Removed Linked List element

Tags: linked-list

I have this snippet of code that remove linked list elements given a value. I am trying to figure out why is it necessary to initialize ListNode p and set it equal to dummy and use the p node to traverse and update the linked list. why can't I just directly use the dummy node to traverse and update the linked list and return the head.

```
public class Solution {

public static ListNode removeElements(ListNode head, int val) {

        ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
        dummy.next = head;
        ListNode p = dummy;
        while (p.next != null) {
            if (p.next.val == val) {
                p.next = p.next.next;
            } else {
                p = p.next;
            }
        }

     return dummy.next;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you tried running it traversing by the dummy node? What happened? Because from what I see, it should work, as p is a copy of dummy. You should return head in the end of the function though, but that's not a problem.

Comment: actually, I did try traversing by the dummy node. I test it and it did work in eclipse. but when I submit it through online judge, it didn't pass

Comment: I'm assuming that you are `free`ing those dynamically allocated elements. `dummy` will need to point to `new ListNode(0)` to be able to `free` it later. If you get rid of the `new ListNode(0)` and the dummy altogether, then yes you won't need dummy in there.

Comment: By traversing using `dummy`, you'll be seriously leaking memory by losing the newly allocated `ListNode(0)`.

Comment: If you omit `dummy` and `new ListNode(0)` altogether, then you have to take care of the condition where `head` may be `NULL`. When `head` is `NULL` `p.next` will segfault because it will evaluate to `NULL.next`.

Comment: @alvits I see what you are saying. so dummy and head nodes need to stay where it is originally  in order to free the nodes later.

Comment: You are returning `dummy.next` not `head`, therefore it will not matter where `head` ends up pointing.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(0);
```

should be

```
ListNode dummy = new ListNode(-1);
```